# What is the best way of grouping buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am making a quiz app and I want there to be 13 different answer choices each with their own button. Do I make IB Action for all of them? There has to be a more efficient way of doing this, right?

Comment: Try `UITableView`

Comment: @bsod I only want buttons. No table

Comment: If you want an efficient way of displaying 13 buttons that constantly display different data based on a single data source (i.e. the question being displayed), a table with 13 rows of buttons is the most efficient way of managing that.

Comment: @bsod Maybe it is, but it looks ugly. I want different sizes and certain placement for each button

Comment: A table doesn't look like anything, it only looks as ugly as you design it. If you want to display buttons all over the screen, perhaps in a circle, just place 13 buttons onto the screen and either manage their actions separately or direct all of their actions to the same method. This is all very basic stuff, there shouldn't be anything tricky here.

Answer (score 1):

You can set each button specific tag:
[image]

And then in IBAction check this tag as:

```swift
button.tag
```

Comment: How would you connect them? How would you determine which button was pressed?

Comment: @Benjamin you connect them all to same IBAction, but each button has own tag (aka button0 with tag 0, button1 with tag 1...)